Creating a Virtual Environment
I'm using Python 3.13.0, and I'm having difficulty creating a virtual environment.  I believe I've downloaded most of the logic to create one, except for one file.  The error I'm getting is:
"failed to locate pyvenv.cfg: The system cannot find the file specified."
I'm really new to Python.  So, I've been trying to follow along in the 'Learn Python Programming' book by Fabrizio Romano, and I've not been able to create that virtual environment.  I also see where I'm supposed to run the '/bin/activate' script, but I don't see that script.  Can someone please help?
I've tried executing the venv launcher from the
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\venvwlauncher filepath, but it's where I got the error.

It would help if you explain how you created the virtual environment in the first place.

Note that, while you might still get useful feeedback, StackOverflow is not the place for personalized technical support. -- The command you are probably looking for is path/to/python -m venv path/to/my-new-venv. If this does not work, there is something wrong with your system.

Here is a simple example showing to activate and deactivate. If you use vscode, you can try this method I posted awhile back.

/bin/activate is a Linux command but your file path is windows. What OS are you running on?
